# How does $\gcd(a^n, b^n) = 1 \implies \dfrac{a^n}{b^n}\not\in\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I don't understand [this proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1932602/567464) for the case where $m^{1/n} \in \mathbb{Q \cap Z}^C$.

> Then $\exists \; a, b \in \mathbb{Z} \qquad \ni \qquad\gcd(a,b)=1 \; \text{  and } \;  m^{1/n} = \dfrac{a}{b}$.
>
> [If $\gcd(a,b)=1$, then $\gcd(a^n,b^n)=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/166839/567464).
>
> Thus, $m = \dfrac{a^n}{b^n} \in \mathbb{N}$.

But how do I deduce the contradiction: $\dfrac{a^n}{b^n} \not\in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: The only way $\frac{a^n}{b^n}$ can be an integer is if $b^n|a^n$.... But if $\gcd(a^n,b^n) = 1$ that is impossible.

Answer (score 2):

$\gcd(a^n, b^n) = 1$ means $a^n$ and $b^n$ have no common factors other than 1 (or $-1$).

$\frac {a^n}{b^n}$ means $b^n$ divides evenly into $a^n$ and $b^n$ itself is a factor of $a^n$.  So $a^n$ and $b^n$ have $b^n$ as a factor in common.

The only possible way these are *both* true, that $a^n$ and $b^n$ have no common factor othere than $1$, and $a^n$ and $b^n$ have $b^n$ as a common factor is if $b^n = \pm 1$.

So $b = 1$ and well, .... now what?

Answer (score 1):

If  $\frac {a^n}{b^n} = m$  for some $m \in N$, then $a^n = m\times b^n$ and thus you have $b^n|a^n$. So, $gcd(a^n,b^n)= b^n$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $|b| \neq 1$. Further assume that $a^n = kb^n, k \in \mathbb{N}$. Using Bezout's lemma: $ra^n + sb^n  = 1$ for some $r,s \in \mathbb{Z}\implies rkb^n+sb^n= 1\implies b^n = \pm 1\implies |b| = 1$, contradiction to $|b| \neq 1$. Thus the assertion follows.